# $watch not firing as many times as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I am expecting `$watch` to fire `x` times if you change the variable it is watching `x` times. In a little example I put together, I am changing the value of variable `$scope.foo` 3 times, but the associated `$watch` only runs once...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='myApp'>

    <div ng-controller='MyCtrl'></div>

    <script>
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

      myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.$watch('foo', function(oldVal, newVal) {
              console.log(oldVal, newVal);
          });

          $scope.foo = "foo";
          $scope.foo = "bar";
          $scope.foo = "baz";
      });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Would anyone be able to explain what the reason for this is, or a different approach I can take to receive the desired outcome?

I am expecting the following console output:

```
undefined foo
foo bar
bar baz
```

but get...

`baz baz`

### edit: another example

```
  myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.$watch('foo', function() {
          $scope.bar = 'bar';
      });

      $scope.foo = "foo";

      // now the value of $scope.foo has changed, I was expecting the $watch to have run at this point.
      // Apparently is has not because $scope.bar is still undefined. Accessing $scope.bar in a $timeout works, but is there a better way?
      console.log($scope.bar)
  });
```

Comment: The question is how is foo updated? If it is only ever updated in the controller, then there is no need for a `watch`! Regular javascript will do here. If it is updated through a form input (for example) then yes you can use a `watch`. What you can also do is to refactor the `watch` function into a separate function call that can be run initially to set everything up. See my example in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `$watch` will only fire once during each angular $digest cycle! (If watching a property that is - the simplest scenario).

The three changes you are making to `foo` are all occurring during the same cycle. And angular will compare the values before the cycle and after the cycle.

For your situation, you need to trigger a new cycle by, for example, changing the values inside a `$timeout`.

**Edit**

For your example you could do something like this

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "foo";
    // run on controller init
    fooWatch();
    // watch for changes
    $scope.$watch('foo', fooWatch);

    function fooWatch() {
        $scope.bar = 'bar';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a `$digest` cycle isn't run everytime you change a variable in your scope (fortunately).

It is triggered when you use `$timeout` though.

What's your use case ?

BTW using `$watch` in a controller is often not a good practice and easily avoidable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes sense. I've added another example to the OP with a scenario which mirrors my real use-case: An update of variable (`foo`) triggers an update of another variable (`bar`) within the `$watch` on `foo`, but the updated value of `bar` isn't available immediately. If I wrap the `console.log($scope.bar);` in a `$timeout` then it all works, but is there a better way to approach this problem perhaps?

Comment: Why don't you just call the function you want executed when you update $scope.foo **in your controller** ? Using `$watch` only really makes sense when you're expecting your variable to be modified from a view update, not when you're manually changing from inside your controller.

I'm still not really sure of what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: The example is simplistic, but perhaps an important detail that I omitted is that the first variable (`foo`) can be updated from either the view or the controller. So the suggestion from both you and @Umair of having a plain function for the controller, and leaving $watch to just detect changes from the view makes sense. My key misunderstanding of $watch was that it would be a good place to put code that should be run if a variable changes either as a result of an action in the view or some other update in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The change is too quick for angular, with `$timeout` it works :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='myApp'>

    <div ng-controller='MyCtrl'></div>

    <script>
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

      myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
          $scope.$watch('foo', function(oldVal, newVal) {
              console.log(oldVal, newVal);
          });

          $scope.foo = "foo";
          $scope.foo = "bar";
          $scope.foo = "baz";
        
          $timeout(function(){
            $scope.foo = "foo";
          },0)        
          $timeout(function(){
            $scope.foo = "bar";
          },0)        
          $timeout(function(){
            $scope.foo = "baz";
          },0)
      });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*See [How does AngularJS's $watch function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634666/how-does-angularjss-watch-function-work)*

Comment: It's not too quick! `$watch` is fired only during `$digest` cycle and it's not running every time you change value (unless it's managed by ngModel) What you did here is to provoke digest 3 times